# How to check if a file name contains a correct amount of numbers in python?

Tags: python, file-read

I am writing a program which filters files placed in a specific folder and I need to check whether they have this structure: some_name/+++/++/++++.format, where + represents any digit.

Here is how my code starts:

```
import glob

path = "_path_"
File_list = glob.glob(path+"/*")

for item in File_list:
  if item == path + *something*:   <-------- This is my problem
    print (True)
```

I would appreciate any help. I am working with Python 3.6.

Comment: use regex to match the name of the file with your format https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html

Comment: You can use `\d{3}/\d{2}/\d{4}`

Comment: You could loop through the the characters in the file path string and count how many digits appear in it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about some regex to match that pattern:

```
import re

pat = re.compile(".*\/\d{3}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}\.format")
if pat.match(item):
    # Your code here
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use glob pattern:

```
File_list = glob.glob('/'.join((path, *('[0-9]' * n for n in (3, 2, 4)), '.format')))
```

Answer (score 1):

This should help-

```
import re    
f = 'fname/123/45/6789.txt'
if re.match('^\w+/\d{3}/\d{2}/\d{4}', f):
    print("Correct file name format")
```

Output:

```
>> Correct file name format
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
regex = r"\w+\/\d{3}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}"
test_str = ("some_name/123/12/1234")
matches = re.search(regex, test_str)
if matches:
     print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

*Use Regex*